# SimplePie through CraftCMS adding #? to feed URL

Tags: php, rss, simplepie

Okay - simple details first:

Feed URL: http://feeds.wired.com/wired/index

When I access this directly through simplepie and not CraftCMS, the feed loads without issue. When I access it through the CMS template system it throws an error saying the returned XML is effectively garbage. Looking into this, its because the feed host is returning a page not found.

I have dug through the code to find out why it is a page not found on a valid URL and found that in the file:

```
/library/simplepie/registry.php
public function &create($type, $parameters = array()) (around line 160)
```

Now in this function I see that a new reflection class is created and new InstanceArgs are sent the parameters. At this point the Feed URL gets changed from:

http://feeds.wired.com/wired/index
to
http://feeds.wired.com/wired/index?#

Effectively this new URL with the added `?#` on the end is causing the feed site to return a page not found. And hence all my errors...

This is beginning to hit the end of my abilities - and I would like to know what is causing the ?# to be added and if there is a way to prevent it? Or any other possible solutions to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't explain why it works outside of Craft and not inside, but it definitely looks like a SimplePie bug to me.

Just created an issue and pull request with the fix for them (https://github.com/simplepie/simplepie/issues/366) and will see about updating it in Craft itself.

Update: looks my fix didn't broke some of their tests, so we won't be putting that into Craft, but they have acknowledged it needs to be fixed.

Comment: Cheers Brad,you've dug further than i managed and help much appreciated. I'll look at the areas you found and see what i can tweak!!! Cheers Again Brad.